# qBitTorrent save to sftp location

Tags: ssh, sftp, multiarch, qbittorrent

Title pretty much says it all. Does anybody know how to make the qBitTorrent client store its downloads data on a sftp or ssh location?

I tried to Set Location $\rightarrow$ and browse to the sftp location, but when returning, qBitTorrent continued downloading to the default location.

I could use sshfs, but the main reason for doing this is because I don't have the storage capacity on the local machine to download/store the torrents in the first place.

Thanks for reading.